# Create Decoder From Filename Access problems in Direct 2D

Tags: c++, bmp, direct2d

I dont work long with DirectX 2D an wantet to load a Bitmap. But every time i tryed it there was an error : "Access violation while reading at position". I seached, some say thy to
use png instead of bmp, but it also didint work.

I dont know what to do :(. I hope someone can help me.

The code:

CPP (with the problem)

```
#include "SpriteSheet.h"

SpriteSheet::SpriteSheet::SpriteSheet(wchar_t DateiName, Grafik::Grafik* gtx)
{
    this->gfx = gfx;
    bmp = NULL;
    HRESULT hr;

    // Unsere Fabrik
    IWICImagingFactory *wicFabrik = NULL;
    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WICImagingFactory, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, 
IID_IWICImagingFactory, (LPVOID*)&wicFabrik);

    // Decodiert die Bilddatei ***!!!!!ERROR by Crete Decoder From Filename!!!!!***
    IWICBitmapDecoder* wicDecodierer = NULL;
    hr = wicFabrik->CreateDecoderFromFilename(&DateiName, NULL, GENERIC_READ, 
WICDecodeMetadataCacheOnLoad, &wicDecodierer);

    // Animation
    //unsigned BildZahl = 0;
    //hr = wicDecodierer->GetFrameCount(&BildZahl);

    // Ließt die einzelnen Bilder von der Datei (0 indiesem Fall ist die "Frame" Zahl)
    IWICBitmapFrameDecode* wicBild = NULL;
    hr = wicDecodierer->GetFrame(0, &wicBild);

    // Erstellungs des Konvertierers
    IWICFormatConverter* wicKonvertierer = NULL;
    hr = wicFabrik->CreateFormatConverter(&wicKonvertierer);

    // Konvertieren in RGBA
    hr = wicKonvertierer->Initialize(wicBild,GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppPBGRA, 
WICBitmapDitherTypeNone, NULL, 0.0 , WICBitmapPaletteTypeCustom);

    // Konvertierung zu "D2D1Bitmap"
    gtx->GetRenderZiel()->CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap(wicKonvertierer, NULL, &bmp);

    if (wicFabrik)
    {
        wicFabrik->Release();
    }
    if (wicDecodierer)
    {
        wicDecodierer->Release();
    }
    if (wicBild) 
    {
        wicBild->Release();
    }
    if (wicKonvertierer) 
    {
        wicKonvertierer->Release();
    }
}

// BildZeichnen
void SpriteSheet::SpriteSheet::Zeichnen(float Durchsichtigkeit)
{
    if (Durchsichtigkeit == NULL)
    {
        Durchsichtigkeit = 1.0f;
    }
     SpriteSheet::gfx->GetRenderZiel()->DrawBitmap(bmp, D2D1::RectF(0.0f, 0.0f, bmp- 
   >GetSize().width, bmp->GetSize().height), Durchsichtigkeit, 
    D2D1_BITMAP_INTERPOLATION_MODE::D2D1_BITMAP_INTERPOLATION_MODE_NEAREST_NEIGHBOR, 
    D2D1::RectF(0.0f, 0.0f, bmp->GetSize().width, bmp->GetSize().height));
    }

SpriteSheet::SpriteSheet::~SpriteSheet()
{
    if (bmp)
    {
        bmp->Release();
     }
}
```

Header :

```
#include "Grafik.h"
#include <wincodec.h>

namespace SpriteSheet
{
    class SpriteSheet
    {
        Grafik::Grafik* gfx;
        ID2D1Bitmap* bmp;
    public:
        SpriteSheet(wchar_t DateiName, Grafik::Grafik* gtx);

        ~SpriteSheet();

        void Zeichnen(float Durchsichtigkeit);
    };
}
```

Comment: Why DateiName is a `wchar_t` and not a `wchar_t*` (or LPCWSTR as defined in .h) ? What do you pass to your function?

Comment: wchar_t DateiName. try const std::wstring& DateiName and then use static_cast<LPCWSTR>(DateiName.c_str()) where you need the filename.

Comment: ok thx i try it out. I pass a define from my resurce.h file

Comment: I tried both, but none of them changed the access distribution